# Sinch iOS Callkit/Pushkit

Tags: ios, sinch

I developed a module with Sinch Call for iOS and I'm in trouble with the PushKit/Callkit integration.

Everything works in a development environment. When a start a call, the callee received the Push from Pushkit and report to Callkit.

But when I try with my app build for production I didn't receive the push (not sure about that) and the Callkit notification never appear.

During the initialization of the managedPush, I use the `SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic`

On the Sinch Dashboard I put my Voip Certificate and my two Push certificate, one for dev and one for production, but it still not working

Maybe I miss something?

Thanks!

PS: If someone is able to explain to me the difference between SINAPSEnvironmentDevelopment and SINAPSEnvironmentProduction it will be nice! :)

Comment: Its apples sandbox and proudction enviroments, you can read more about them here 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/aps-environment
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Sorry I cant be more specific. Try and force it to production to use the production cert.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! It was what I thinking about this variable.

Answer (score 2):

SINAPSEnvironmentDevelopment is when you are installing app to device from xcode
SINAPSEnvironmentProduction is when you distrubute app to App Store or Testflight

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

`SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic`

set the environment manually to

`SINAPSEnvironmentProduction` before publishing to TestFlight or App Store.
Set the environment to development when testing from xcode. This will give you more control in future debugging.

Also note that Apple has changed the VOIP push certificate and you need to update yours in your Sinch dashboard.

Lastly, if you are not receiving your voip push from testflight and you are certain your code is set to SINAPSEnvironmentProduction AND your Sinch dashboard is using a valid voip push certificate then your device may be blacklisted by pushservice and is blocking voip pushes for your app.

**Follow these steps to reset your push permissions for your App**

1. Delete your app
2. Open Settings set time 1 day ahead
3. Restart your device
4. Install your App from TestFlight / App Store
5. Accept permission requests inside your app
6. Open Settings set time to automatic
7. Restart your device

You have now reset your push permissions and unblocked your device and app. Voip push should now come through.